# How to upload expo PDF document to Firebase Storage?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, firebase-storage

using the expo-document-picker library, how do I upload the file to my firebase storage? I tried with the code below but after I send the uploadDocument function, expo returns the error:

> [Error: Call to function 'ExponentFileSystem.getInfoAsync' has been rejected.
> → Caused by: The 1st argument cannot be cast to type kotlin.String (received Null)
> → Caused by: Cannot assigned null to not nullable type.]

```
import * as DocumentPicker from 'expo-document-picker';
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';
import {firebase} from '../../services/config_storage2';
import { Permissions } from 'expo';


export default function TesteUploadDocumento() {
  const [documento, setDocumento] = useState(null);
  const [uploading, setUploading] = useState(false);

  const pickDocumento = async () => {
    try {
        const result = await DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync({ copyToCacheDirectory: true, });
        if (result.type === 'success') {
            const { uri } = result;
            setDocumento(uri);
            alert(uri);
            console.log(result);
        } else {
            Alert.alert('Nenhum documento selecionado');
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}

const uploadMedia = async () => {
    if (!documento) {
        Alert.alert('Por favor, escolha um documento primeiro');
        return;
    }

    setUploading(true);

    try {
        const blob = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(documento, {
            encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64,
        });

        const filename = documento.substring(documento.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        const ref = firebase.storage().ref().child(filename);

        await ref.putString(blob, 'base64');
        setUploading(false);
        Alert.alert('Documento Subiu!!!!');
        setDocumento(null);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        setUploading(false);
    }
}
```

tried adding the function copyToCacheDirectory: true, but it didn't work, it's as if the picker didn't select the file, it always remains null in my opinion